# How to intercept requests to a service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I define a `Service` named `my-backend` in Kubernetes. I would like to intercept every request sent to this service, what is the proper way to do it? For example, another container under the same namespace sends a request through http://my-backend.

I tried to use Admission Controller with a validation Webhook. However, it can intercept the CRUD operations on service resources, but it fails to intercept any connection to a specific service.

Answer (score 2):

There is [no direct way](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11221) to intercept the requests to a service in Kubernetes.

For workaround this is what you can do-

1. Create a sidecar container just to log the each incoming request. [logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)
2. Run `tcpdump -i eth0 -n` in your containers and filter out requests
3. Use [Zipkin](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/tracing-tutorial-zipkin/)
4. Creating service on cloud providers, will have their own logging mechanism. for ex - load balancer service on aws will have its logs generated on S3. [aws elb logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service mesh such as [istio](https://istio.io). An istio service mesh deploys a [envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io) sidecar along with every pod. Envoy intercepts all the incoming requests to the pod and can provide you metrics such as number of requests etc. A service mesh brings in more features such as distributed tracing, rate limiting etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking into `istio` rather now. I am wondering if `ambassador` is something similar to it?

Comment: ambassador is ingress gateway and can capture client traffic to the first service inside your cluster but if you hit another service inside the cluster from the first service then that is not captured. Ambassador is north south traffic whereas Istio can capture both north south as well as east west traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes NetworkPolicy object will help on this.  A network policy controls how group of pods can communicate with each other and other network endpoints. You can only allow the ingress traffic to the my-backend service based on pod selector. Below is the example that will allow the ingress traffic from specific

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
   name: ingress-only-from-frontend-to-my-backend
   namespace: default    
spec:
   podSelector:
      matchLabels:
          <my-backend pod label>
   policyTypes:
   - Ingress
   ingress:
    - from:  
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            <Frontend web pod label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I hope to find a constrain on service scope rather than pod. Also, I would like to do some complicated intercept like whether allowing a request given its content.

Comment: @AugustinPan were you able to find any solution for this?